# Adding margins to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Using the basic starting app from XCode for a navigation based application, I'm trying to change the frame of the UITableView.

Here's what i'm trying to do:

[image]

http://cl.thickshake.co.nz/BVTE

All I want to be able to do, is to set the tableView.view.frame to be a different size than the space provided for it.

If this isn't possible, how would I go about doing it by building up the views (if i create a UIView and add a UITableView to it, I can control the size, but then I seem to have trouble wiring up the NavigationBar etc to work the same way).

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that your `UITableView` has to be embedded in a `UIView`. Best way to do that is to create a new `UIViewController` (without a table view) and add a table view into it. Don't forget to connect up the `UITableView`'s `delegate`/`datasource` to your controller and implement the `UITableViewDelegate`/`UITableViewDataSource` methods.